Adverbial phrases after intransitive verbs


He comes.
He comes here.


Can we just say 'He comes.' instead of 'He comes here.'?
I think 'He comes.' is a perfect sentence. For example:


Does he come here?
He comes.



There are very few contexts where it would be natural in English to use Simple Present like this, which is why your examples look a bit weird to native Anglophones. But there's nothing remotely unusual about Is he coming here?, He came quickly, I will come at once.

@FumbleFingers Can you give me some of those contexts, please?

Even with "do-support", Does he come here? is an unlikely question unless it includes an adverbial modifier (Does he come here often?). As James points out below, present simple is used for facts that are generally or always true. So He likes chocolate is natural. But note that He is liking chocolate is unnatural ("Indian English"), and He plays tennis doesn't mean the same thing as He is playing tennis. Simple Present means he can or he often plays tennis (but probably not right now), whereas Present Continuous means he's playing at time of speaking.

The most natural reply would be "Yes, he does".

"He comes" is grammatically correct sentence.  It is about the most simple sentence possible.
Neither is particularly common or natural. The present simple is used for facts that are generally or always true, and an action statement like "He comes" is not "generally" true.  It might be true "right now", and you could use a present progressive tense.
"He's coming" is very natural.  "He's coming here" adds to the meaning, as it tells you that he is not only getting closer, but also that his destination is "Here".  If "Here" is the important idea, you might want to emphasise it.

Is he coming here? But I thought we were meeting at the park! I haven't tidied my room.

